# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException for ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, indexing

I get an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException for this code.

```
private List<Integer> LoeschenX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> LoeschenY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i : LoeschenY) LoeschenX.add(LoeschenY.get(i));
```

Comment: _IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())_

Comment: I think you misunderstood how a for each loop works. `i` is not the index, it's the int value hold by each Integer object during the iteration. I.e if your list contains 4,-5,12, i will be equals to 4 (iteration 1), -5(iteration 2) and 12(iteration 3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
for (int i : LoeschenY)
```

you are looping over the **elements** of `LoeschenY`, not on indexes. You may want to iterate over indexes so you can use `get(i)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LoeschenY.size(); i++) 
    LoeschenX.add(LoeschenY.get(i));
```

Remember that `get(index)` will return the value in an specific index.

**Edit:** You can also try

```
for (int i : LoeschenY) 
    LoeschenX.add(i);
```

since `i` takes the values of the elements of `LoeschenY`, you will add these values to `LoeschenX`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be iterating over the elements in the Y array, but the `get` method actually uses the *element* as an *index* the way you're doing it.

Try

```
for(int i : LoeschenY)
    LoeschenX.add(i);
```

Or

```
for(int i = 0; i < LoeschenY.size(); i++)
    LoeschenX.add(LoeschenY.get(i));
```